# My bundle is not automatically registered

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, symfony-flex

I created a independant bundle following the [symfony tutorial](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-bundle/extracting-bundle) but since I moved my bundle out of my app nothing work anymore.

going step by step I realized that flex doesn't auto-register my bundle into my project. Normally it should be automati as my bunlde include `"type": "symfony-bundle"`. I think I made error in some naming (a in this [issue](https://github.com/symfony/flex/issues/193)) but I cannot put my hand on it:

Can someone with experiment can just have aquick look at the following code and explain me what I did wrong ?

```
//the bundle json

{
    "name": "btba/chat-bundle",
    "type": "symfony-bundle",
    "description": "Chat generator for Symfony applications",
    "keywords": ["chat", "generator"],
    "homepage": "https://github.com/12rambau/Chat-bundle",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Project Contributors",
            "homepage": "https://github.com/12rambau/Chat-bundle/blob/master/CONTRIBUTORS.md"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Btba\\ChatBundle\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

```
// the bundle load in my app 
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "btba/chat-bundle": "*@dev"
    }

    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "../ChatBundle"
        }
    ]
}
```

```php
// the bundle class 

namespace Btba\ChatBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class BtbaChatBundle extends Bundle
{

}
```